# CoreData: How to correctly use migratePersistentStore to create a backup copy

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, core-data

I'm really struggling with this. I'm trying to create a backup of my active core data base. According to Apple the best option is not to use the File Manager but the method migratePersistentStore. However I don't really understand this. I have my PersistentStoreCoordinator in my AppDelegate. So if I'm migrating the persistent store my coordinator will lose it after successfully moving it correctly? So the store is now just at the new location but not at the old anymore? So do you have any example program code for this of how my app still could keep running with the original copy?

Or can't i just copy all files using the filemanager with the same prefix instead of migrating?! So much easier...

Comment: I'm struggling with the same problem. Did you find a way to achieve a backup using migratepersistentstore and keep the current store in the same location?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a separate NSPersistentStoreCoordinator for migration only, and continue using your regular one for CoreData stack. Also you can use NSMigrationManager for migration:

```
NSMigrationManager* manager = [[NSMigrationManager alloc] initWithSourceModel:sourceModel
                                                             destinationModel:targetModel];

BOOL migratedSuccessfully = [manager migrateStoreFromURL:sourceStoreURL
                                                    type:type
                                                 options:nil
                                        withMappingModel:mappingModel
                                        toDestinationURL:destinationStoreURL
                                         destinationType:type
                                      destinationOptions:nil
                                                   error:error];
```

Also I'm not sure you can migrate when your DB is opened, probably you'll need to lock it or something.

Comment: To create a new temporary NSPersistentStoreCoordinator is the key. Use it for migration and then just forget it. I have a class where I keep the whole stack so I just created a brand new stack, use it for migration and forget it with no worries.

Comment: Do you happen to have an example of migrating the temp store to iCloud?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't have opportunity to work with iCloud CoreData yet.

Comment: @ViktorKucera do you zip the data beforehand? also, do you use migrateStoreFromURL: to create iCloud backups as well?